# how to mount a luks-encrypted file?

Tags: centos, luks, dmcrypt

I had a good-working system. Cent OS 6. But after I made a reboot luks-partition has been unmounted. And our system administrator have a weekends now :(

Please help me to mount a luks partition again.

I know the path to encrypted file and password.

System administrator's records says: "Encrypted file located at /path/file and mount to /crypt. Password is xxxxx" That's all.

Before reboot the server I made a records of 'mount' command, the related partition was:

> /dev/mapper/crypt_fun /crypt ext4 rw,relatime,barrier=1,data=ordered 0
>   0

Now I try this commands:

> cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/loop0 /path/file

type a password

> mount /path/file /crypt

But nothing works good :( Please help me.

Comment: Take a look inside /etc/crypttab. Are there any clues in there?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given the above, my guess is that you would need to do something like this.

- First make your file accessible via a loopback device

  - losetup /dev/loop/0 /path/file
- Open the loopback device to crypt_fun

  - cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/loop/0 crypt_fun
- Mount it

  - mount /dev/mapper/crypt_fun /crypt

Comment: You can also skip to step 2 if you simply supply `/path/file` and `crypt_fun` it will automatically handle the loop device and creating the mapper, then you can proceed to step 3.

Comment: @dragon788 yeah, I think when I was answering this back in 2013, I was using old at the time distro that wasn't automatically creating loop devices.